# python merge set of fronzensets into one set

Tags: python, set, set-union

I am trying to merge sets defined in a set and this is what I have now

```
a = frozenset([1,3,4])
b = frozenset([1,2,3,4,5])
s = set()
s.add(a)
s.add(b)
merged = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(s))
```

In practice, `s` may contain many frozensets. Is there better ways to do it? It feels like a `reduce` case, but

```
from functools import reduce
merged = reduce(|, s)
```

doesn't work.

Also

```
merged = reduce(set.add, s)
```

doesn't work because the elements of `s` are frozensets.

Comment: `|` as a standalone function is known as [`operator.or_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have more than two frozensets, create a container (e.g., list) of them and apply a union:

```
listoffrozensets = [a,b,...]
frozenset().union(*listoffrozensets)
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, really,  but just use the method *directly* from the class without instantiating a useless instance: `frozenset.union`

Comment: I would say this is the "correct" way of doing this. `reduce` is likely less efficient. Anyway, in Python, `reduce` is not encouraged. This is the reason it was removed form the `built-ins` namespace in python 3.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga True, `union` is about 20% faster than `reduce`, at least as reported by my `%timeit`.

Comment: I just hit into a problem when `listoffrozensets=[]`, then I got error. But `frozenset().union(*[])` still works.

Comment: @nos Good point! `frozenset().union(*listoffrozensets)` works, too.

Answer (score 9):

You *can* use reduce, just use the appropriate function:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> frozenset.union
<method 'union' of 'frozenset' objects>
>>> reduce(frozenset.union, [a,b])
frozenset({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
>>>
```

You were on the right track with `|`, but `|` is an operator in Python, and can't be substituted for a function. But when you want to do that, import the operator!

```
>>> import operator
>>> reduce(operator.or_, [a,b])
frozenset({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
```

Comment: Note you'll need e.g. `frozenset[int].union` to avoid `Type of "union" is partially unknown` if you're `typing`